# Visual Web Part or Web Part?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I need to create a sharepoint 2013 web part and i don't know what kind of web part i must use.

Why i have to use Visual Web Part insteade of Web Part or Web Part insteade of Visual Web Part.

Thank You Guys

Comment: Kindly add some scenarios or some detailing about the information you are looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's recommended to use Visual Web Parts over traditional web part for the following reasons:

- No need to code everything from scratch, Simply drag and drop items from the Toolbox onto your custom controls to create a Web Part UI.
- You also get the code-behind file where you implement the UI logic.
- Technically, the SharePoint Visual Web Part is a web user control that is hosted inside a standard Web Part.

Check also a good comparison between web part and visual web part to can decide which one should to use at

- [Using Visual Web Parts vs. Traditional Web Parts in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh857549%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Difference between WebPart & Visual Web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52075/difference-between-webpart-visual-web-part)